# Python/wxPython: auinotebook get all pages

Tags: python, wxpython

I have an auinotebook, is there anyway to get a list of all pages in the notebook?  When the user selects an action from a list, a new page is added to the notebook.  If they select that action again, then the page should not be added again (instead, that page will be selected for them).  I can't see to figure out how to do this??
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using wx.lib.agw.aui.AuiNotebook:

```
import wx.lib.agw.aui as aui

class MyNotebook(aui.AuiNotebook):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        ''' More pythonic way to get a specific page, also useful for iterating
            over all pages, e.g: for page in notebook: ... '''
        if index < self.GetPageCount():
            return self.GetPage(index)
        else:
            raise IndexError
```

Now you can iterate over the pages of the notebook:

```
notebook = MyNotebook(parent)
notebook.AddPage(someWindow, "page 1")
notebook.AddPage(someOtherWindow, "page 2")
for page in notebook:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for!  As a side-note, do you know what the difference is between wx.aui and wx.lib.agw.aui?  I just googled it but didn't get any good results...

Comment: wx.aui is the wxWidgets version of AUI, developed in C++. wx.lib.agw.aui is a port of AUI in Python and wxPython, developed by Andrea Gavana. Both are included in wxPython. The advantage of Andrea's version is that it's in Python (easier debugging) and that he accepts patches.

Comment: Thanks for the information Frank.  I guess my real question is what the differences are, or if the community has a "preferred" version that is recommended.  A wiki on the wxPython page comparing and contrasting them would be nice.  From your comments, it sounds Andrea's version might be the preferred one.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, I'm only a tiny part of the community, but I prefer Andrea's version for the reasons stated. Task Coach (http://taskcoach.org), of which I'm one of the developers, makes heavy use of Andrea's version of AUI. It (wx.lib.agw.aui) works without major flaws on all platforms. In the few cases where we had problems it was quite  advantageous that wx.lib.agw.aui is written in Python since I could easily debug the code, fix bugs myself and submit patches to Andrea. Doing that in the C++ wxWidgets version of AUI would have taken me an order of magnitude more time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which AuiNotebook you're using. Is it the one that comes with wx.aui or wx.lib.agw.aui? Either way, I would think you could use GetChildren() to get a list of the notebook's panels and iterate through those as necessary. There's also a GetPageCount that you might be able to use in conjunction with GetPageInfo and GetPageText (these last three methods are in the agw version...not sure if they're included in the other). See the documentation for more information: http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/AGW_Docs/aui.auibook.AuiNotebook.html#aui-auibook-auinotebook

Or you could cross-post to the wxPython user's list.